# firebase storage not created new folder at child android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I tried create folder per user by unique value (auth UID). 
I did:

```
        private String profileId;
        private StorageReference mStorageRef;

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        profileId = bundle.getString(Constants.PROFILE_ID_KEY);
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("images");

        StorageReference imageStorageRef = mStorageRef.child(profileId);

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageName = "img" + timeStamp + "_.jpg";

            imageStorageRef.child(imageName).putFile(picUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri();
                }
            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        }
                    });
    }
```

It is put all the images into specific profileId even when I sign out and connect with other profileId. 
any help will be appraised

Answer (score 0):

Your passing Constant Profile id : `profileId = bundle.getString(Constants.PROFILE_ID_KEY);`

Instead of just get user directly by using firebase auth.

```
if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null){
    uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
}else{
    //do what you want
}
```

Comment: I fetch it exactly like you wrote from other fragment. because that it is in bundle. I have value in this variable. the problem focuse is in mStorageRef.child(profileId) who not created folder with value of profileId in firebase storage.